# IRepository - Entity implementation

Tags: repository-pattern

I'm using Repository and UnitOfWork pattern in order to mantain decoupled code and to achieve a simple way to test my application.

The inner implementation use EntityFramerowk with DB first and all works fine.

Tomorrow, I might want use some other concrete repository implementation such as file system rather than database, so some repository method like Find, or Delete could be difficult to accomplish, because my entities doesn't implement anything about primary-foreing keys and so on. It implies my entity research on repository should looks for all fields matching with T object parameter.

So, is it good practice enforce my entities for some interface implementation? For instance:

Is there some available example or tutorial about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> some repository method like Find, or Delete could be difficult to accomplish, because my entities doesn't implement anything about primary-foreing keys and so on. It implies my entity research on repository should looks for all fields matching with T object parameter.

That's how NOT to implement the repository. A repository interface (contract) should be ignorant of the underlying implementation details such as Entity Framework. Only this way you can have a different implementation of the repository and achieve seaparation of concerns. Also, testing code that uses the repository should not involve EF or db at all.